# Solving system of equations using Chinese remainder theorem

Tags: modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations, computer-science, computational-mathematics, chinese-remainder-theorem

I have a system of equations on that I would like to solve programatically:

$(x + a_1) \bmod b_1 = 0$

$(x + a_2) \bmod b_2 = 0$

$...$

$(x + a_i) \bmod b_i = 0$

$a$ and $b$ are given, and I would like to find the smallest positive solution for $x$. The numbers are too big to iterate through all possible solutions. I think it should be possible to solve it using the Chinese  remainder theorem, but I haven't been able to get from one to the other. How can I translate this problem into a problem that can be solved using the CRT?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) to format your posts.  To begin with, surround math expressions (including numbers) with `$` signs and use `_` for subscripts.  `$x_1$` comes out as $x_1$.

Comment: Thank you. I tried to update it now.

Comment: Is it the same $a_1$ and $b_1$ for each equation?

Comment: No, sorry. I messed it up when I edited it.

Comment: Your system of equations is the same as solving $x\equiv -a_i \pmod{b_i}$.

Comment: Thank you @peterwhy! If you post this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system of equations is the same as solving $x\equiv -a_i \pmod{b_i}$.